# What should I have seen in order to better understand "Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

I started watching *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (not yet finished, no spoilers please) and I don’t understand the motivation and anger of Wanda. I believe I have watched every Marvel movie including the first Doctor Strange, although I have not seen the Wanda Vision series. But I remember very little about her.

Now I am considering pausing and re-watching a previous MCU movie to get some context. The question is, which one? And, optionally, should I bother?

Comment: Even after watching Wandavision, her behavior doesn't make much sense. That's one of main reasons why this film is worse then Wandavision.

Comment: @Mithoron What? Why do you say that?

Comment: Say what? That Strange 2 pretty much wasted what Wandavision built, as far as Wanda is concerned? That they made some boogeyman of her?

Comment: I feel like this was fairly well explained, if not completely spelled out word for word -- the Darkhold corrupts people who use it, and they are eventually consumed by it. The Darkhold is the villain throughout the film, not Wanda; she's its victim (although not the only one), and in the end, she triumphs over it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I don’t understand the motivation and anger of Wanda.

*WandaVision* would better help you understand her motivation and anger. Significant events happened in *WandaVision* that led to Wanda's present state in *Multiverse of Madness*.  I'd say it's a better prequel to *Multiverse of Madness* than *Doctor Strange* (2016).

<sup>Putting the rest of my answer in spoiler markup because OP said "not yet finished, no spoilers please."</sup>

> *WandaVision* reveals how Wanda created her children, then lost them, and more importantly, where she gets possession of the Darkhold, leading to her being corrupted by it. This then leads to her finding out about the other versions of her children in the multiverse, then leading to the events of *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*.

Comment: And to the OP's question of "should I bother?":  WandaVision is quite good and (in my opinion and [the opinions of many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_accolades_received_by_WandaVision)) worth watching if you have access to it.

Comment: WandaVision is indeed very good and well worth watching. But DS&TMOM is starting to show the difficulty of accessing the MCU, where you not only have to have seen a few movies, but also entire serials, before watching the latest release.

Comment: @HorusKol Agreed.  It's pretty clear that upcoming Avenger's movies are going to be pretty dependent on things that happened in the Loki mini-series too.

Comment: If you just know that significant things have happened that aren't in *any* MCU movie, and pay close attention, I think the dialogue in Multiverse of Madness when Strange goes to talk with Wanda the first time does a decent job of describing the critical points.

Comment: Having seen the first season of *What If?* would help too, but not nearly as much as a *Wandivision* (and not for anything related to Wanda / the Scarlet Witch).

Comment: Caught up with the entire MCU now, and agree that WandaVision is the best "prequel", although I still feel that they left some gaps, as there's a considerable difference between her state of mind when the series ended, and how she is in the movie. I guess much of it is implied as they show her reading the book in the after credits of the show.